# Unable to extract Unique Identity for Emails sent from Safaricom Internal Mails ie Message ID (PHP IMAP)

Tags: php, laravel, outlook, gmail, php-imap

I am having a challenge,I am unable to extract a unique field from emails sent directly from Safaricom Internal Mails to our Customer Service Mailbox.

All other mails received from different senders have the unique field: Message ID - As seen below;

```
From: John Doe <johndoe@domain.com>
Message-ID: <1erty5.987h55585.160987743@domain.com>
Subject: Test Mail'
```

However, mails sent from Safaricom external emails ie M-PESABusReversals@Safaricom.co.ke have the unique identifier Message ID.

I am using PHP Laravel Imap.

I would like to know if there's an extra unique field that identifies unique emails. Or if there's a way to obtain the Message ID.

Comment: `Message-ID` usually _is_ what gets used for this, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-ID _"I would like to know if there's an extra unique field that identifies unique emails."_ - no generally recognized one, that would be understood the same way as a Message-ID by common clients, as far as I know. Whether this particular sender adds anything unique, can't really tell you - go look at the headers of a couple such mails, and see if you can spot anything.

Comment: Take a look at the message headers to see if you can spot anything - in Gmail, click "View Source". In Outlook, open the message, then click the small "+" button in the bottom-right corner of the Tags ribbon group.